# How to find if an integral is possible to compute: Failing to solve integral for quadratic functional

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, optimization

I am trying to solve the below integral, and no computational method seems to be capable of solving this, nor can I do it by hand. Any ideas?

> $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}[a(t)((2\dot{x^*}\dot{\eta} + \dot{\eta}^2)+b(t)(2\eta x^*+ \eta^2)]\mathrm{d} t$$

$x=x(t):[t_0,t_1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a curve in $C^2$ with boundary conditions $x(t_0)=x_0$ and $x(t_1)=x_1$

where $a(t)$ is a $C^2$ function and $a(t)\geq 1$ and $b(t)\geq 0$ for all $t\in[t_0,t_1]$

$x^*$ satisfies the boundary conditions $x^*(t_0)=x_0$ and $x^*(t_1)=x_1$

Some working:

> Left integral:
> $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}a(t)(2\dot{x^*}\dot{\eta}+\dot{\eta}^2) \mathrm{d}\,t$$
> $$u=a(t)\dot{\eta},\quad v'=2\dot{x^*}+\dot{\eta}$$
> $$u'=\dot{a}\dot{\eta}+a\ddot{\eta},\quad v=2x^*+\eta$$
>
> $$=\left[a(t)\dot{\eta}(2x^*+\eta)\right]_{t_0}^{t_1}-\int_{t_0}^{t_1}(\dot{a}\dot{\eta}+a\ddot{\eta})(2x^*+\eta)\mathrm{d}\,t$$
>
> $$=a(t_1)\dot{\eta}(t_1)(2x^*(t_1)+\eta(t_1))-a(t_0)\dot{\eta}(t_0)(2x^*(t_0)+\eta(t_0))$$$$-\int_{t_0}^{t_1}2x^*\dot{a}\dot{\eta}+\dot{a}\dot{\eta}\eta+2x^*a\ddot{\eta}+a\ddot{\eta}\eta\mathrm{d}\,t$$
>
> $$=a(t_1)\dot{\eta}(t_1)(2x^*(t_1))-a(t_0)\dot{\eta}(t_0)(2x^*(t_0))$$$$-\int_{t_0}^{t_1}2x^*\dot{a}\dot{\eta}+\dot{a}\dot{\eta}\eta+2x^*a\ddot{\eta}+a\ddot{\eta}\eta\mathrm{d}\,t$$

I don't even think Cleo could solve this monster.

Comment: What does $dt\, dt$ mean?

Comment: @GregMartin They are the bounds for each of the integrals